# VBA for Data Web Scraping

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I want to get some data from Url . but getting some error. as I am not expert in VBA  please anyone try to solve my queries here is my code .. I want to scrape some information from urls in excel . like title, tel no, website reviews, actually I dont know what kind of error is going on

```
Public Sub Data()

'On Error Resume Next

Dim html As HTMLDocument
Dim Re, Cr, cipherDict As Object
Dim sResponse, cipherKey, Str, SG As String
Dim myArr, RsltArr(14) As Variant

Set Re = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
Set Cr = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
Set cipherDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Set html = New HTMLDocument

URL = "https://www.google.com/maps/place/Silky+Beauty+Salon/@22.2932632,70.7723656,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x3959ca1278f4820b:0x44e998d30e14a58c!8m2!3d22.2932632!4d70.7745543"
        With Cr
            .Open "GET", URL, False
            .setRequestHeader "If-Modified-Since", "Sat, 1 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT"
            .send
            sResponse = StrConv(.responseBody, vbUnicode)
            s = .responseText
        End With


With html
    .body.innerHTML = sResponse
    title = .querySelector("section-hero-header-title-title").innerText
    phone = .querySelector("[data-item-id^=phone] [jsan*=text]").innerText
    webSite = .querySelector("[aria-label^=Website] [jsan*=text]").innerText
End With

datarw = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    ActiveSheet.Cells(datarw, 1).Value = title
    ActiveSheet.Cells(datarw, 5).Value = phone
    ActiveSheet.Cells(datarw, 7).Value = webSite
    ActiveSheet.Cells(datarw, 1).Select
    ActiveSheet.Rows(datarw).WrapText = False
end sub
```

getting problem to extract title , phone and website in to excel

Comment: Google have an API for retrieving this data - [https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details) - but note that, depending on the volume and type of requests that you make, you may incur a cost for using that API, see [here](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/usage-and-billing)